# This code resulst in "Argument of � has an extra }." unable to identify the cause. I have reused this code from working code

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=2cm]{geometry}
%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}
\newcommand{\rgb}{\rowcolor[rgb]{0,1,0}}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e, eqparbox}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{number}{RGB}{204,95,8}
\definecolor{keyword}{RGB}{255,0,72}
\definecolor{param}{RGB}{0,179,218}
\definecolor{enum}{RGB}{0,122,113}
\definecolor{bool}{RGB}{116,19,232}

\title{\textbf{Quick Start}}
\author{Myname\\Version 2.14}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use the `utf8x` option

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
that worked